# Поиск по нескольким файлам

Tags: python, поиск

Как реализовать поиск по 100+ базам, разом?

```
with io.open('file.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if text in line:
            print(line)
```

```
with io.open('file2.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if text in line:
            print(line)
```

Все файлы весят около мегабайта, я не смог кинуть код с асинхронкой, т.к его удалил(

Comment: непонятно, мы должны восстановить удалённый вами код?

Comment: что означает "разом" в этом контексте?

Comment: Возможно для базы лучше использовать sqlite3? он быстрее, удобней и имеет больше возможностей

Comment: Если файлы такие маленькие, то у вас код и так моментально отработает, даже если обычный последовательный код в цикле сделать.

Comment: пробовал, но доходит до 75 файла за минут 15

Comment: Хм, очень странно. А на печать много выводится при этом? Может собственно сама печать тормозит? Печать вообще штука тормозная по жизни, её трюками с кодом нельзя ускорить.

Comment: может быть, но я уже все сделал, работает на костылях но как то...

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о базе данных, то лучше читать специальными библиотеками. Можно создать сколько нужно коннекторов к БД и читать из каждой базы в отдельном потоке, для синхронного варианта. Для асинхронного варианта можно использовать [asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently) или [Tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently).

Если же все-таки нужно читать файлы то в этой задаче отлично подходит чтение в разных потоках или процессах.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from pathlib import Path

def read_file(filename: str | Path) -> dict[str, list[str]]:
    res = res
    with open(filename) as file:
        res.append(file.read())
    return {filename: res}



def read_all(path: str | Path, max_workers: int = 100, find_template = '**/*'):
    files = Path(path).rglob(find_template)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
        res =  executor.map(read_file, files)
    return res
```

Такой подходи отлично работает в синхронном контексте. Если программа асинхронная, то следует посмотреть на использование тасков и асинхронных либ для чтения. Так же как вариант можно использовать [loop.run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) если чтение не асинхронное.